# Подсчёт количества букв, цифр и специальных символов в введенной строке python

Tags: python, строки

На вход программа получает строку, например, "*fddfs456*".
Нужно вывести количество цифр, букв и специальных символов в формате:
3
5
2

```
stroke = input()
print(len([i for i in stroke if i.isdigit()]))
print(len([i for i in stroke if i.isalpha()]))
```

Не совсем понимаю, что значит это код и как подсчитать кол-во спецсимволов

Comment: Погуглите что делают функции `isalpha` и `isdigit`. Почитайте про *списковые сокращения*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что значит это код и как подсчитать кол-во спецсимволов
> В данных строках:

```
print(len([i for i in stroke if i.isdigit()]))
print(len([i for i in stroke if i.isalpha()]))
```

Эта конструкция (`[i for i in stroke]`) называется генератор. В нем вы отбираете в список те символы, которые удовлетворяют условию, указанному в генераторе. Метод `isdigit()` проверяет состоит ли строка из цифр, а `isalpha()` проверяет состоит ли строка из букв. Далее вы печатаете длину списков. Подробнее вы можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html). Я бы вам не рекомендовал начинать с генераторов, если вы не знаете работу словарей, списков, строк и их методов. Вот, вариант, понятный и, впринципе, удобный для записи:

```
string = '"fddfs456"'

d = {'Спец.символы': 0, 'Буквы': 0, 'Цифры': 0}
for i in string:
    if i.isalpha():
        d['Буквы'] += 1
    elif i.isdigit():
        d['Цифры'] += 1
    else:
        d['Спец.символы'] += 1

print(d['Цифры'], d['Буквы'], d['Спец.символы'])
```

Answer (score 0):

компактный вариант:

```
s = 'fddfs456!+'

res = [len(list(filter(f,s))) for f in (str.isalpha,str.isdigit,(lambda x: not x.isalnum()))]

print(*res, sep=' ')  # 5 3 2
```